# Dependency Injection for GUI programming

Tags: java, user-interface, dependency-injection

What is the usual way to use dependency injection for GUI programming? For example, if I want a Form which has a Button, do I inject the Button into the Form class, and the add the button to the form as a child in the Form's constructor, or should I just create a new Button in the Form object and not use dependency injection?

Comment: "Usual" way?  Swing programming preceded DI.  Usually it's been done by calling new.  You can use a DI engine like Guice or Spring if you wish.

Comment: What GUI technology are you using?

Comment: It's Java, so Swing is a safe bet.  Could be JavaFX, I guess.

Comment: this could help http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javafx-productivity-2345000.html

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. How to implement your code depends on your actual requirements.

Comment: Things like Form or Button can't really be unit tested. Use MVC pattern, make you view as dumb as you can and unit test Controller and Model. View has to be system-tested.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in injection of button or other UI element with @Inject. You could use DI for some controller injection. Imagine how would configuration look like. It would be spaghetti